# How i store multiple json file data in one scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make when some click on checkbox then it call api and store both data (previous and present).
my function -

```
$scope.cardcall = function (type) { 
        $scope.cityname=cityname;   
        $http({method: 'GET',url: '/api/v1/asas?&filterBy=cards&filterByValue='+type.key}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.deal = data.deals;              
        });                  
    };
```

and my view part -

```
<div class="check_box" ng-repeat="type in card.Cards.buckets">                                                  
<label for="{{type}}">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" {{type.key}}" name="cardname" ng-click="cardcall(type)" /> {{type.key}} 
 </label>
```

When some click fist checkbox then show that data and after that if they click second checkbox then show both data (1st and 2nd).Now it show only one checkbox data(last checked).I don't know is it possible or not because i am new in angular js. I am using angular js 1.2.23

Comment: assign data to different variables and use `ng-show` for each

Comment: Your code example doesn't show us what you really mean. Are you displaying $scope.deal somewhere? Is that what you mean by "show that data"? What is cityname used for? Is that what you are trying to show? Your example just keeps resetting the $scope.deal and $scope.cityname values on every click, not appending or adding new values.

Comment: when some click then need to append card name like 1st click-api/v1/asas?&filterBy=cards&filterByValue=xx card 2nd click api/v1/asas?&filterBy=cards&filterByValue=xx card,yyy card